# IndexedDB persistence in PWA application

Tags: progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

PWA application storage (IndexedDB) isn't able to provide data persistence.

In case that PWA is pinned to home screen it is possible to clear all application data from browser by clearing browsing history.

It might be unclear for users that cleaning browser data can affect pinned application and unsynchronised data will be lost.

Is there any way to avoid this?
The only way I see for now - turn back to native apps.

Answer (score 1):

The clear storage mechanism in browsers is to put the user in control of their device.

This is why you as an application should never (native or web) assume your cached assets are cached.

If it is absolutely important to you to make sure you have core assets and data persisted then you need to have some sort of integrity check when the service worker initiates. That way you can restore cached state in case the application goes offline.

You also need to realize the operating system, looking at you iOS, will purge data when it feels like it (think when the available disk space gets critical), which takes you out fo control. It does this for native apps too as far as I know.

Comment: The problem is not to get the user in control, the problem is that the user wants to delete the Browser cache, not my app data, my users are installing my PWA and then later them are clearing they browser cache, but they can't understand why deleting their browser cache is affecting my App, so a WPA is not a good solution, and NO, native app are not being deleting user data as per my years of experience.

Comment: If you are talking about a user going into their iPhone settings -> Safari -> clear history and website data, then yes it purges everything you have cached, yours and the other PWAs and websites on their phone.
Your service worker should be designed to rebuild the cached assets when it is installed. Never assume anything is cached. User state can be persisted in the cloud, etc to be restored. It all depends on the application personality how far you take it. You should also set user expectations.
I don't know how many go that far into settings, but I suspect few do.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a way around that. The function in Chrome to "clear storage" (for example) does exactly that. I suppose it is reasonable for a user to be able to remove any data from their own device, but I agree it is not a good situation for the developer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

The Storage API provides a `StorageManager.persist()` method to request the user explicit permission to persist data until deleted by the user itself:

```
if (navigator.storage && navigator.storage.persist)
  navigator.storage.persist().then(function(persistent) {
    if (persistent)
      console.log("Storage will not be cleared except by explicit user action");
    else
      console.log("Storage may be cleared by the UA under storage pressure.");
  });
```

If the local storage is running out of space, the User Agent will start automatically pruning cached resourced except the ones set as "persistent". However if the user itself chooses to clear the local data, there is no way to prevent this.

As far as I am aware, there is no event you can intercept in order to detect a browser clear action from the user.

See API reference doc : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/persist